# Angular - Structural directive with embedded view does not pass children to ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got a structural directive that creates an embedded view by looking up a template ref using ng-template. My problem is that from this parent component (with structural directive), I cannot pass down children.

**Parent component with structural directive**

```js
import { ViewChild, Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { TestJsonService } from "../../services/test-json.service";

@Component({
  selector: "xfr-json-renderer",
  template: `
    <template-lookup></template-lookup>
    <div class="NA-TEMPLATE-CHOOSER" *replaceWith="'flexCol'">
      <div>Why can't i pass this down to the child?</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./json-renderer.component.css"],
})
export class JsonRendererComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("childTemplate") childTemplate;
  constructor(el: ElementRef, json: TestJsonService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {}
}
```

**Child component**

```js
import { Injectable, TemplateRef, Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class TemplateStore {
  templates = new Map<string, TemplateRef<any>>();
}

@Component({
  selector: "template-lookup",
  template: `
    <ng-template #flexRow></ng-template>
    <ng-template #flexCol><xfr-flex-col>
      // I want to pass the children into here
    </xfr-flex-col></ng-template>
  `,
})
export class TemplateLookup {
  @ViewChild("flexRow") flexRowTemplate;
  @ViewChild("flexCol") flexColTemplate;

  constructor(private service: TemplateStore) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.templates.set("flexRow", this.flexRowTemplate);
    this.service.templates.set("flexCol", this.flexColTemplate);
  }
}
```

**Structural directive**

```js
import { ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { TemplateStore } from "./../services/composite-template.service";
import { Directive, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[replaceWith]",
})
export class CompositeTemplateDirective {
  @Input() replaceWith: "flex-col" | "flex-row";
  constructor(private service: TemplateStore, private view: ViewContainerRef) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.service.templates.get(this.replaceWith));
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Why can't i pass this down to the child?" and where specifically in the code is your issue?

Comment: If I knew where the issue was would I post it here for help?? That section where I write that comment, the Dom node does not render

Comment: @Terry I think i know what the issue is. I do'nt know how to fix it though. Look at when this is called `<template-lookup></template-lookup>` It sets the templates. Afterwards, the directive is called, but the template has already been set. how to fix this?

Comment: `<ng-template #flexCol><xfr-flex-col>// I want to pass the children into here` I don't understand this. You have template and inside that template you have another component. If you want to pass it inside that component why do you have template above that component?

Comment: What i'm after is using the <xfr-flex-col> component using the structural directive to find this template (*replaceWith="'flexCol'"). My understanding is that's the only way to do it, I need a ng-template reference. I modified this example to try and get this dynamic style of template - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/eggheadio-projects/angular-lessons/tree/template-service/?from-embed=&file=/src/app.component.ts

Comment: Can you provide a sample what the result should be I don't think I understand what you want? Is the sample you provides already a solution for you? Or what you want is to take only the content inside the div with the replaceWith directive and project it somewhere inside the flexCol template when it renders.

Comment: The flexcol component is nothing more than a div with ngcontent as a child. What I want to do is take an element and add the replaceWith directive including a string path for a choice of which component to render. I want to use a div, add replaceWith='flexCol', some children content to have it render using the separate flexCol component

Comment: So, basically you are trying to say that between
<xfr-flex-col>
      // I want to pass the children into here
</xfr-flex-col>
tag you want to pass flexCol and flexRow template from parent. For example, from parent 1 you may pass flexCol so between those tags you will have flexCol template. Similarly from parent 2 you may pass flexRow and child is updated accordingly. Is that what you are trying to imply?

Comment: You want to include the div with replaceWith='flexCol' as the content in the flexCol component? Or just the content inside the div?

Comment: why are you motivated to accomplish this with a structural directive? this kind of feels like it should be a component?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to use internal API for that, what is not the best thing. I would use it until I stay with the same angular version and would test it before every update - then should work stable.

I was able to do the injection with Angular 9, quite sure a similar solution (but different internal API) can be applied for other angular versions.

The main thing for the injection - where to inject the content, in components we could use `ng-content`, but here it wouldn't work, because we have different component contexts. In this case we could use `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]></ng-template>` to tell the script where we want the injection.

here you can find a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-wright-335bm?file=/src/app/json-renderer.component.ts

CompositeTemplateDirective

```js
import {NgTemplateOutlet} from '@angular/common';
import {AfterViewInit, Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {TemplateStore} from 'src/app/TemplateLookup/TemplateLookup';

@Directive({
    selector: '[replaceWith]',
})
export class CompositeTemplateDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() replaceWith: 'flex-col' | 'flex-row';

    constructor(
        private service: TemplateStore,
        private view: ViewContainerRef,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    ) {
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const wrapper = this.service.templates.get(this.replaceWith);
        const source = this.templateRef;

        const view: any = this.view.createEmbeddedView(wrapper);

        let directive: NgTemplateOutlet;
        const nodes: Array<any> = view._lView ? view._lView : view._view && view._view.nodes ? view._view.nodes : [];
        for (const node of nodes) {
            if (typeof node !== 'object') {
                continue;
            }
            if (node instanceof NgTemplateOutlet) {
                directive = node;
            }
            if (typeof node.instance === 'object' && node.instance instanceof NgTemplateOutlet) {
                directive = node.instance;
            }
        }
        if (directive) {
            directive.ngTemplateOutlet = source;
            directive.ngOnChanges({
                ngTemplateOutlet: {
                    previousValue: null,
                    currentValue: source,
                    firstChange: true,
                    isFirstChange: () => true,
                },
            });
        }
    }
}
```

TemplateLookup

```js
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Injectable, TemplateRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TemplateStore {
    templates = new Map<string, TemplateRef<any>>();
}

@Component({
    selector: 'template-lookup',
    template: `
        <ng-template #flexRow>
            <div>
                flexRow template
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #flexCol>
            <div>
                <div>wrap</div>
                <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]></ng-template>
                <div>wrap</div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    `,
})
export class TemplateLookup implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('flexRow', {static: false}) flexRowTemplate;
    @ViewChild('flexCol', {static: false}) flexColTemplate;

    constructor(
        private service: TemplateStore,
    ) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('TemplateLookup:ngAfterViewInit');
        this.service.templates.set('flexRow', this.flexRowTemplate);
        this.service.templates.set('flexCol', this.flexColTemplate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so the most pragmatic thing here seems to be to just put the child you want to pass as a child of the `template-lookup` component and use `ng-content`...

do this in the parent:

```
<template-lookup>
  <div>I will pass to child</div>
</template-lookup>
<div class="NA-TEMPLATE-CHOOSER" *replaceWith="'flexCol'">

</div>
```

and this in the child:

```
<ng-template #flexRow></ng-template>
<ng-template #flexCol>
  <xfr-flex-col>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </xfr-flex-col>
</ng-template>
```

and that will solve your problem / fulfill the stated requirements.

You could also consider a rewrite to your service to solve timing problems between templates being set and gotten once and for all:

```
import { Injectable, TemplateRef } from "@angular/core";
import {ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs';
import {map, filter, distinctUntilChanged} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) // provide appropriately, root for example
export class TemplateStore {
  private templates = new Map<string, TemplateRef<any>>();
  private tmpSource = new ReplaySubject<Map<string, TemplateRef<any>>>(1);

  setTemplate(key: string, template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.templates.set(key, template);
    this.tmpSource.next(this.templates)
  }

  getTemplate(key: string) {
    return this.tmpSource.pipe(
      map(tmpMap => tmpMap.get(key)),
      filter(tmp => !!tmp),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
  }
}
```

and make the associated changes in the directive and child components...

```
export class CompositeTemplateDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() replaceWith: "flex-col" | "flex-row";
  private sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private service: TemplateStore, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.service.getTemplate(this.replaceWith).subscribe(t => {
      this.viewContainer.clear()
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(t)
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
  }
}

export class TemplateLookup {
  @ViewChild("flexRow") flexRowTemplate;
  @ViewChild("flexCol") flexColTemplate;

  constructor(private service: TemplateStore) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.setTemplate("flexRow", this.flexRowTemplate);
    this.service.setTemplate("flexCol", this.flexColTemplate);
  }
}
```

functioning example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygdveu

it's been pointed out that this doesn't support nesting... so make the following adjustments and you can nest. in template lookup, you'll need to use the `SkipSelf` modifier in your constructor, and also provide the TemplateStore... in the case of no nesting, this will have no effect, `SkipSelf` just tells the injector to start looking for the service at the parent rather than at the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "template-lookup",
  template: `
    <ng-template #flexRow>FLEX ROW</ng-template>
    <ng-template #flexCol>
      FLEX COL
      <div class="flex-col">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  `,
  providers: [TemplateStore]
})
export class TemplateLookup {
  @ViewChild("flexRow") flexRowTemplate;
  @ViewChild("flexCol") flexColTemplate;

  constructor(@SkipSelf() private service: TemplateStore) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.setTemplate("flexRow", this.flexRowTemplate);
    this.service.setTemplate("flexCol", this.flexColTemplate);
  }
}
```

then you can nest to your hearts content like so:

```
<template-lookup>
  <div>I can pass this to the child!</div>
  <template-lookup>NESTED</template-lookup>
  <div class="nested-content" *replaceWith="'flexCol'"></div>
</template-lookup>
<div class="NA-TEMPLATE-CHOOSER" *replaceWith="'flexCol'">

</div>
```

which is a little ugly, as you need to repeat the template-lookup component, but it does get the job done. This works by allowing the directive and template lookup to communicate with a different copy of the TemplateStore so you can nest different content.

working example of this variant: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpner2

Comment: He wants to pass the content of `class="NA-TEMPLATE-CHOOSER"` further, not `template-lookup`. That's the thing making this question interesting - https://take.ms/qRmZB, when expected like that: https://take.ms/mUWjQ. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The templates are defined in template lookup. If you just move the child content to be children of template lookup, then you can use ng content to project to the templates. That’s the point. Why does it matter where you define the child template so long as it’s at the same level and provides the same flexibility

Comment: try to use `<div class="NA-TEMPLATE-CHOOSER" *replaceWith="'flexCol'">nested1</div><div class="NA-TEMPLATE-CHOOSER" *replaceWith="'flexCol'">nested2</div>`, it won't work with your code, it supports only 1 type of nested content. Whereas the goal is to inject a custom content into a custom parent component, and which component is parent should be based on `setTemplate` and its key. Imagine you have another `template-lookup` components with different templates inside but with the same keys for `setTemplate` and at any point in time you want to inject there a custom content, maybe several times.

Comment: You can set up nested projection with the right set up but no you this won’t work with nested directives in the same template directly using the same keys. You’d need multiple lookup directives with their own children and keys. If supporting nesting in this way is a requirement, I could adjust my answer but it seems contrived imo and I’m being pragmatic. Multiple template look up components with the same keys is also contrived as they’d be arbitrarily overwriting each other in the service

Comment: It does work with nested directives, you can check live demo in my answer. I just meant - in your solution you show how to do a regular injection in a regular component, when the question is how to pass one templateRef into another templateRef. Imagine that `flexCol` is a `div`, in some skin theme you want it to be a `td`. Then you would use a different `template-lookup` that has inside `td` instead of `div`. WIth normal injection it mens you have to update code everywhere replacing `<template-lookup>my content</template-lookup>` with `<template-2>my content</template-2>`

Comment: My set up doesn’t work with nested directives is what I am saying and If OP is ok with that, then this is a simple, pragmatic approach And it’s a trade off with complexity, if not, I can adjust. The question is how to get the child content projected to the template, that’s done here. I don’t really find the situation you’re describing to be a short coming. Swapping our Templates situationally is the same in any case.

Comment: now it's fixed to work in a nested fashion with some minor adjusting